# Ordinal Numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does there exist an implementation of [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) in python?

An example use-case is the following:

- We want to maintain a [sorted dictionary](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html) indexed by numbers.
- Over time we may insert an **arbitrary** number of "standard" elements (idx, e)
- The dict should also contain certain "special" elements (idx, w) which should always appear at the end, after all other elements.

A very clean solution (*) would be to simply index the elements with [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), so the "standard" elements would use the indices 0,1,2,3,... and the "special" elements could be assigned to ω, ω+1, ω+2, ω+3, ... Obviously this approach also is incredibly powerful in its generalization power.

Of course there are alternative solutions, for example one could maintain multiple lists. However this has the disadvantage that if we want to iterate over **all** elements, we need to work through the lists one-by-one. With ordinal number indexing, one would just have to iterate over one list.

(*) At least from my perspective as a mathematician

Comment: Wouldn't tuples work fine as your keys? Your "standard" elements could use key `(0, i)` and your "special" elements could use key `(1, i)`. I don't think you need some abstact mathematical construct.